# Regex | If present then stop

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex that matches `everything` (any character) in:
`everything.html`
`everything`
match `.+` until `.html` or end of string.
the `.html` is optional, but if it is present, stop matching.

Comment: How is your regex failing?

Comment: Could use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): [(.*?)(?=\.html|$)](http://regex101.com/r/qD6vJ6)

Comment: Clarification needed. 'everything.except.htmlisgood', would that need to match "'everything.except.html" (because 'html' is found), or the full string -- because it's equal to `.+`?

Comment: Regarding edit: no you have not :) See `everythinglol`

Comment: @Robin Can you tell me why that is?

Comment: I flagged to have this question deleted and a moderator declined it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
^.+?(?=\.html|$)
```

- `(?=...)` is a look ahead, it will match if what's after the current character is matched by what's inside the lookahead, without "selecting" these characters. It's a zero width check
- `.+?` will match everything (at least one character) but stop at the first occurrence of `.html` (therefore avoiding to match `123.html123` in `123.html123.html`)
- `^$` match the beginning and end of the string

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/zC4xF8)

Regarding your solution, `[^...]` stands for "one character, any character except one of those listed inside".